# Eclipse project artefacts in Maven repository

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-jdt

I want to use some of the libraries produced by the Eclipse project through Maven. I 've had a look at the main Maven repo and while it looks like that there are a few projects already imported, their versions are old and some important ones are missing (e.g. cdt). Is there any Eclipse project official Maven repository? If not, what would be the best option to use current versions of libraries such as the JDT compiler in a maven-enabled project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it yourself using the [Maven Tools 4 Eclipse](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Maven_Tools_4_Eclipse).

Eventually, all the Eclipse bundles will show up as artifacts on [maven.eclipse.org](http://maven.eclipse.org/).